# x:Bind TwoWayBinding not working on Textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, two-way-binding, xbind

I am trying to make the two way binding work on `Textblock` with compilation binding `x:Bind`

**Problem:**
Even though setting TwoWay bind mode and PropertyChanged source trigger. Can not get it to work. When the object property balance changed in code behind it does not get updated in UI.

Below is the code.

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="Balance"
            Text="{x:Bind classObject.Balance,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**Code-Behind**

```
private ClassName classObject = new ClassName() { Name = "Foo",Balance = 100 };
public Observable ViewModel { get; } = new Observable();
private void NavLinksList_ItemClick(object sender,ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    classObject = new ClassName() { Name = "Blah",Balance = 10 * new Random().NextDouble() * (50 - 1) + 1 };
}
```

**Observable**

```
public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Alternate solution**

Set `Textblock.Text` in code behind manually.

But the issue is property changed event is supposed to work and automatically update the text block without explicit coding.

I searched other questions , but couldnt find the similar one.

Comment: What does "not work" mean here? What do you expected to happen and when?

Comment: >>"But the issue is property changed event is supposed to work and automatically update the text block without explicit coding."

Comment: class property is same, so I think it should. dont it?

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, please explain the downvote, downvoting without feedback wont help improve the posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the data-bound `Text` property of the `TextBlock` you should set the source property that it's bound to, i.e. the `Balance` property of `classObject`. Also note that the `ClassName` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications.

Setting the `classObject` field to a new instance of a `ClassName` is not supposed to update the `TextBlock`, unless you call `Bindings.Update()` afterwards.

Comment: I removed setting it to new instance code , but it still does not work and `Observable` class has implemented `INotifyProperyChanged` which is in turn made as `ViewModel` property. I have used `ObservableCollection` in similar fashion , that works though.

Comment: You are not binding the TextBlock to the Observable so why would this matter? You are binding to className.Balance, aren't you? Why are you even creating an Onservable? You don't seem to use it somewhere anyway.

Comment: How do I bind TextBlock to Observable, I thought making it as class property is enought since I have getter set to new instance of ViewModel i,e Observable. Do I need to declare ClassName object in Observable class?

Comment: What property of the Observable do you want to bind the TextBlock to...!? The Observable class has no properties.

Comment: all the properties of `className` object.  Calling `Bindings.Update()` solved the issue. Thanks a lot!